# Rhino Mock calling an async Task Method

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I am trying to mock a dbWriteService Method that returns a aggregate exception when i call it, even though everything is not null. I am farely new to mocking and rhino mock, so I do not really get the problem.

This is the part I want to mock in the function i want to test:

```
public async Task<bool> SaveDataAsync(object data) {
...
    await _dbWriteService.UpdateAsync(data);
...
}
```

I am mocking the writeService like this:

```
dbWriteService = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IDbWriteService>();
dbWriteService.Expect(service => service.UpdateAsync(null));
var wasSaved = subject.SaveDataAsync(data).Result;
dbWriteService.AssertWasCalled(service => service.UpdateAsync(null));
```

and i am getting an exception like this:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at ClearingDataRepository.<SaveDataAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in ....\ClearingDataRepository.cs:line 170
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at UnitTests.Services.ClearingDataRepositoryTests.SaveDataAsync_Sucess() in ....\ClearingDataRepositoryTests.cs:line 90
```

I tried a few things with the mocked function but i do not get the reason why this stuff does not work. Could anybody explain this to me?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, you should change `GenerateStub` to `GenerateMock` so you can use mock features. Secondly, it would be better to use `await` instead of `.Result()` in your test, and the test method return type can be `async Task`. And thirdly, seems like Rhino Mock wants you to set return value for a mock, which could be set to `Task.FromResult(0)`.

For example, to make sure `UpdateAsync` was called with `null` value and final result was `true` you could write following test with MSTest.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var dbWriteService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDbWriteService>();
        dbWriteService.Expect(service => service.UpdateAsync(null)).Return(Task.FromResult(0));
        var subject = new Class1(dbWriteService);

        // Act
        var result = await subject.SaveDataAsync(null);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
        dbWriteService.AssertWasCalled(service => service.UpdateAsync(null));
    }
```

Where `Class1` is the class with `SaveDataAsync` method in my case.